# What does the phrase "something is red hot" mean?

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning, it-its-itself

Recently read when I read an IT paper, I encountered a phrase, "Red Hot". what does it mean?

Below is the full sentence :

> The DevOps space is **red hot**, but as many enterprise are quiclky beginning to learn, it's no easy, so it's critical to ensure that your environment is prepared.

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 2):

***[Red-hot](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/red-hot)*** is used figuratively to indicate something that is very successful and popular:

> extremely popular

(M-W)

> creating much excitement, demand, or discussion:
>
> - *The new toy robot is a red-hot item this Christmas.*

(Dictionary.com)

Also simply  ***[hot](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hot?s=t):***

> (Informal) popular and commercially successful; in demand; marketable:
>
> - *The Beatles were a hot group in the 1960s.*

Answer (score 1):

In this context, red hot means that something is popular or growing. Other usages include: something that has a high temperature, something that is very spicy, or someone that is very attractive.